# How to create an array with predetermined norm and mean?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to create an random array with a "norm" of 1 and "mean" of 0. I can use `numpy.random.normal()` to get the "mean" I want, but how can I create an array such that `numpy.linalg.norm(array)` returns the number that I want?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Yeah, what if the result of numpy.linalg.norm is 0? Then this doesnt work.

Comment: This would be extremely bad luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`numpy.random.normal`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.normal.html) with the `size` argument will give you an array with values that are drawn from a distribution with a mean of 0. The mean value of the array will not be 0, however (it is more likely to be close to 0, the larger the array is).

But you can easily fix that by subtracting the mean of the array.

Once you have this, you can change the norm of the array to 1 by dividing by its norm. This will not change the mean, because it is 0.

```
def create(n):
     x = numpy.random.normal(size=n)
     x -= x.mean()
     return x / numpy.linalg.norm(x)
```

#### Example

```
>>> a = create(10)
>>> a
array([-0.48299539,  0.06017975,  0.23788747, -0.31949065,  0.56126426,
       -0.33117035,  0.40908645,  0.01169836, -0.1008337 , -0.0456262 ])
>>> a.mean()
-1.3183898417423733e-17  # not exactly 0 due to floating-point math
>>> numpy.linalg.norm(a)
1.0
```

Notice how for `n=2` there are exactly 2 arrays satisfying these conditions: Those that contain both the positive and the negative square root of 1/2:

```
>>> for _ in range(5):
...     print(create(2))
...
[-0.70710678  0.70710678]
[-0.70710678  0.70710678]
[-0.70710678  0.70710678]
[-0.70710678  0.70710678]
[ 0.70710678 -0.70710678]
```

Comment: As a side note, using normal distribution is essential for this solution to work, as using any other distribution, e.g. uniform will result in a random vector that is not uniformly distributed in vector space with norm of 1 an mean of 0